# How to reverse only half of the tab?

Tags: java

how can I revers only half of the table ? For example:
i have: TAB = {1,2,3,4,5,6} and I would like to get TAB2: {1,2,3,6,5,4}.

Now, I revers all tab like this:

```
int tmpl;
    int l = tab2.length;
    int pol = l/2;

    for (int i = 0; i <= pol; i++){
        tmpl = tab2[i];
        tab2[i] = tab2[l-1-i];
        tab2[l-1-i] = tmpl;
    }
```

Comment: Start your loop at `l-1` and iterate to the end

Answer (score 1):

Make two separate arrays for each half.

```
public static int[] splitArray(int start, int end, int[] array)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length / 2];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        newArray[j] = array[i];
        j++;

    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Have a method that reverse an array. Pass each array.

```
public static int[] reverseArray(int[] array)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        newArray[j] = array[i];
        j++;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Now combine the two arrays.

```
public static int[] combineArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    int j = 0;
    int[] combinedArray = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        combinedArray[j] = array1[i];
        j++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
    {
        combinedArray[j] = array2[i];
        j++;
    }
    return combinedArray;
}
```

How the main method would look.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] TAB = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int[] split1 = splitArray(0, TAB.length / 2, TAB);
    int[] split2 = splitArray(TAB.length / 2, TAB.length, TAB);
    split1 = reverseArray(split1);
    split2 = reverseArray(split2);
    int[] TAB2 = combineArrays(split1, split2);
    for (int i = 0; i < TAB2.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(TAB2[i]);
    }


}
```